# How can I fix the Study Error: "Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0. When making a trailing stop?

Tags: pine-script, highest

I am trying to make a trailingstop multiple of the ATR, since a buy or sell signal has occured. Naturally I try the `barssince(long)` function, to determine the amount of bars since the buy signal. Then I use the `highest` function to find the highest ATR value since my buy signal. My code is:

```
atr = atr(input(defval=14, title="ATR"))
Multip = input(0.2, minval = 0)
lower = low - atr * Multip
upper = high + atr * Multip


barssincelong = barssince(long)
barssinceshort = barssince(short)
islong = barssincelong < barssinceshort


plotlower= highest(lower, barssincelong)
plotupper= lowest(upper, barssinceshort)


stoplossline = islong ? plotlower : plotupper


plot(stoplossline)
```

"long" and "short" are defined in the code above that, but that is irrelevant.

For some odd reason, this script gives a Study Error that says:

"Invalid value of the 'length' argument (0) in the 'highest' function. It must be > 0.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: This code snippet doesn't compile. Please provide a full working script to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code , here `nz()` is used to avoid errors due to returning of `na` when `ta.barssince()` used  and `math.max()` used to get rid of 0 returning from `ta.barssince()`. Hence you will not send 0 as length in the `ta.highest()` or `ta.lowest()` function.

pine script version 5 used :

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

atr = ta.atr(input(defval=14, title="ATR"))
Multip = input.float(0.2, minval = 0)
lower = low - atr * Multip
upper = high + atr * Multip

ema=ta.ema(close,20)
long=ta.crossover(close,ema)
short=ta.crossunder(close,ema)

barssincelong = nz(ta.barssince(long))
barssinceshort =  nz(ta.barssince(short))

islong = barssincelong < barssinceshort
plotlower= ta.highest(lower, int(math.max(1,barssincelong)))
plotupper= ta.lowest(upper,  int(math.max(1,barssinceshort)))
stoplossline = islong ? plotlower : plotupper


plot(stoplossline)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `barssince` returns the value `na` if no bar with the specified conditions is found. This situation is possible on the very first bars. For the functions `highest` and `lowest` the argument `length` greater than zero must be specified. You need to define in the script how to handle such situations.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that it is not possible in pinescript to have a variable as lenght in "highest" and "lowest" functions. I eventually had to hardcode it. Still much appreciation for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error and have a solution like this

```
barssincelong = barssince(long)
if na(barssincelong ) or barssincelong ==0
    barssincelong := 1
```